# Autoincrement ID java db

Tags: java, database, netbeans, derby

I have such a problem.

I have in my database 10 students.
When I removed from a database student with ID 2 and I want to add a new student with ID 2,which will replace the earlier removed student, it gets ID 11 , no 2.

I use script

```
CREATE TABLE student (
    id_student INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1), ......
```

I use Java DB.

Is there any script which is able to solve this my problem?

Comment: Re-using the identity column is a very bad idea. Suppose student 2 scored an A, you replace him/her with a new student, then suddenly that student also with id 2, will have an A.

Can you post the code how you are inserting the new student "2" in your database?

Answer (score 3):

Since you said "GENERATED ALWAYS", Derby is **always** going to pick a new identity value.

If you had said "GENERATED BY DEFAULT", then Derby would only pick a new identify value if you didn't provide one.

In that case ("GENERATED BY DEFAULT"), you could specify a new record with the value 2, and as long as there was no existing record with value 2, your new record would be accepted.

More information here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/ref/rrefsqlj37836.html

Answer (score 1):

Generally, It is good practice to soft delete a record from database by setting a flag rather than deleting whole record and It is better to use auto increment which increments the ID associated. 
You can get the active number of records by just counting the records with flag set.
I hope the answer helps.

Answer (score 1):

It took a loooong time to figure this out. In Netbeans you can run this script to add the table:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE
(
   "ID" INT not null primary key
        GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
        (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
   "NAME" VARCHAR(99)
);
```

Notice the **UPPERCASE.** If ID and NAME are not uppercase, this does not work.